# Correct usage of Neither, nor, not,

Tags: conjunctions, negation, neither-nor

A• Secession is the solution, neither election nor restructuring.

B• Secession is the solution, not election nor restructuring.

Please, which of the above is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Sentence A is incorrect, sentence B is slightly off.

Nathan M is correct that "Neither *X* nor *Y*" and "Not *X* nor *Y*" are both legitimate structures. However, the sentence you present has a more dominant structure: "*X* is the solution, not *Y*". "Neither" is never the right word in this structure.

The slight error in B is more nuanced. As I said before, "Not *X* nor *Y*" is a legitimate construction, but only as distinct phrase. On its own "*X* nor *Y*" isn't sensible, and the "not" in the sentence is a separate conjunction. The correct form of the sentence is "Secession is the solution, not election **or** restructuring."

Answer (score 0):

*Nor* is “used before the second or further of two or more alternatives (**the first being introduced by a negative such as “neither” or “not”**) to indicate that they are each untrue or each do not happen.” Both *neither*  and *not* are negatives, so they’re both legitimate structures.

*Quoted material is Oxford Dictionary’s definition for “nor.”*

Comment: Both are correct? Tell me what A means.